How do I restore a wordpress backup from scratch?
My server was compromised, so I'm trying to manually restore a backup of http://thesealords.com. My hosting is through GoDaddy, and here's what I've done so far:

Fully reset/wiped the server
Created a new site via godaddy admin panel. Did not install Wordpress via Godaddy application installer at this time.
Re-uploaded all files via FTP to the proper directory.
Manually created a new DB via phpMyAdmin. DB name, username, and password for this DB are also new.
Imported the backed up SQL database. I can see all the WP related tables and, at least as far as I can tell, everything looks okay.
Modified wp-config.php to use the new DB name and credentials from step 4.

The tutorial I've been following says these steps should work. But the site is literally blank and I'm at a loss for what to do next. I can't get to wp-admin or even like an error page. It's literally just loading blank white pages. The only thing I can get to load is a static index.html page I've uploaded.

Did you make sure the correct "Site Address URL" and "WordPress Address URL" in the DB in the wp_options table?

The URL hasn't changed, but I checked anyway. siturl = https://thesealords.com. I couldn't find a field that matched "wordpress address URL" or anything like that in the options table.
One thing I did notice is that some other options in wp_options seem to be pointing to an old directory... like upload_path, recently_edited, etc. I think godaddy automatically creates some directories when you do an automatic WP install (which is what I did last time, before the site was compromised)

Another thing I've considered is that maybe I have some plugins enabled that could be messing with things? Not sure how to disable plugins without access to the admin.

Figured it out. I had to delete .htaccess (which I had re-uploaded from the old site)

good work! submit the answer to your own question. some people dont read these comments.

Your site back to work. Well done!

In this case, I had to delete the .htaccess file in the site root. I had backed it up (and restored it) without really thinking about it. After deleting it, the site worked perfectly.
